# Adding a Tiled map to Phaser and issues with character changing facing

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tiled

I've created a Tiled map for a game I'm making in Phaser and despite following a tutorial, I can't seem to get it to load. I'm making the game in javascript using webstorm. The naming of everything seems ok and I'm getting no error pop ups but it's loading only a black background instead of the map.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
function preload() {

game.load.spritesheet('player', 'res/player_strip8.png', 80 , 190);
game.load.spritesheet('player-right', 'res/player_right.png');
game.load.spritesheet('player-left', 'res/player_left.png');
game.load.tilemap('map', 'res/Game_map.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
game.load.image('tiles', 'res/back-ground.png');}

var map;
var tileset;
var layer;
var player;
var facing = 'left';

function create() {
map = game.add.tilemap('map');
//game.stage.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

   players = game.add.group();
players.enableBody = true;
createPlayer("");

map.addTilesetImage('Back-ground', 'tiles');
groundLayer = map.createLayer('GroundLayer');

Cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}
function update() {
playerUpdate();
}
function createPlayer(x,y){
var player = players.create(0,0,'player-right');
player.body.bounce.y = 0.5;
player.body.gravity.y = 300;
player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
}
function playerUpdate(){
game.physics.arcade.collide(players, players);

players.forEach(function (p) {
    p.body.velocity.x = 0;
    if(Cursors.left.isDown){
       //players.create('player-left');
        //players.animation('left')
        p.body.velocity.x = -150;
        //player = players.create(0,0,'player-left');
    } else if (Cursors.right.isDown){
       //players.create('player-right');
        //players.animation('right')
        p.body.velocity.x = 150
       // player = players.create(0,0,'player-right');
    }
    if (Cursors.up.isDown && p.body.touching.down  ){
        p.body.velocity.y = -350
    }
})
}
function createPlatform() {
}
```

Comment: Does it show any kind of error? What is the output on the console?

Comment: All it shows is a black screen. It runs fine code-wise, with no errors on the console.

Comment: After you create the layer, add the following statement
`groundLayer.resizeWorld()`
If it still doesn't work then share your tilemap json file here.

Comment: Take a look at this example https://github.com/thefailtheory/zeldajs/tree/master/tutorials/tuto3